# wordpress admin not working with domain name mapping

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, domain-mapping

I had wordpress site on LAMP server without domain name mapping. I am able to access site with IP `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx` without any issue.

`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx` pointing to sub-domain folder on server

But now after mapping domain name I am able to access front end but admin showing blank page with domain name, but with IP both working.

Checked view source it's showing some iframe with reference to IP. I have also tried to update all links in database with domain name but still same issue. Also, tried with dedug true but showing no error message, in error log as well.

Below is the view source of admin section domain.myportal.com/wp-admin

```
<head>
  <title>title  </title>
  <META name="description" content="portal ">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx//wp-admin" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 04 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

I have replaced all links in database with domain name and also run a quick search in code files for hardcoaded link, but it's not there. Can anyone tell me from where its showing in view source (also double slash in frame src).

Comment: What URL is configured at [general options](http://192.237.169.17/wp-admin/options-general.php)?

Comment: it's domain name deals.anilabsinc.com

Comment: It is spelled without the "/" sign after it?

Comment: Try inputting [http://deals.anilabsinc.com/](http://deals.anilabsinc.com/) there

Answer (score 3):

Check you config file where you add extra '/' at the end of the home or site url or current site url.

also check in database.

Comment: that should not be because everything working fine with ip. And I don't have these settings  home or site url or current site url in my config file.

Comment: Yes I can also but am not able to spot from where it's coming.Searched in code files and database no where am able to find IP

Comment: Check in wp_config.php and in wp_option table (siteurl and home).

Comment: Checked, everything is OK, no slash at last and in wp_config I don't have such setting.